# Debugger windows has a different locale language

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Hi I have a little problem with my vscode. The local language is set in english. Everything is in english except the debugging window. It is in spanish, i'm a native spanish speaker but 99% of programming info is in english. I don't want a

> Todas las excepciones, Punto de interrupción de ruta no establecido...

When everything else is in english. Any idea why that happens?

[Spanish and English](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNvx5.png)

Comment: This is very interesting.  I have not been able to reproduce the issue on my side.  In your locale.json do you see `"locale":"en"`?

Comment: Also, do you have any language packages installed? Check under your extensions.  You could try uninstalling the Spanish one if you have it.